# How can I write an excel function with "dynamic" values?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I hope to explain what I need.

I need to write an excel formula where I have to link values from differents sheets by looking the name of the sheets and the position from a grid/matrix

In the picture belowe there is an example where I need to link the value from sheet(MINT);column(A);lane(22)

I would like to write a formula and drag and drop it for all the value of the matrix

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `INDIRECT` function, e.g.:

`=INDIRECT("MINT!A22")`

Having that you can write it for one cell, now just extend it for the matrix:

`=INDIRECT($A3&"!"&$B3&D$1)`

It compose the address of the cell, just need to take care of the correct combination of absolute and relative references.

[image]